# Can I set the value of a boolean parameter inside Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline that takes a boolean parameter as input. However, I need to be able to set the value of this parameter programmatically inside the pipeline based on some conditions. Here is the snippet of my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    booleanParam(
      defaultValue: true,
      description: 'This is a boolean parameter',
      name: 'MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM'
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
          // some condition
          def myBooleanValue = true
          // I need to set the value of MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM based on myBooleanValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using the setBuildParameters method like this:

`setBuildParameters([[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM', value: true]])`

But this throws an error that says: "No such DSL method 'setBuildParameters' found among steps". I've also tried setting the value of MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM using the params object like this:

`params.MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM = true`

But this doesn't seem to work either. Is it possible to set the value of the MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM parameter inside the pipeline based on the myBooleanValue variable? If so, can someone please provide an example of how I can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may also consider using Active Choices plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/  This plugin allows to set build parameters depending on other parameters BEFORE build start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik it is not allowed to change `params` from pipeline script,
however you may modify `env` as a workaround:

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        booleanParam(
          defaultValue: true,
          description: 'This is a boolean parameter',
          name: 'MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM'
        )
    }

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('before') {
            steps {
                echo "before env   : ${env.MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM}"
            }
        }
        stage('reset') {
            steps {
                script{
                    env.MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM = false
                }
            }
        }
        stage('after') {
            steps {
                echo "after env   : ${env.MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
before env   : true
...
after env   : false
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to do the job! 10x a lot!

Comment: Note that on first run of the pipeline, the output of the first stage actually is `before env : null`, because the parameter `MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM` actually isn't defined yet. The first run will just add the parameter to the job configuration. Similarly, if you change a parameter definition in the Jenkinsfile, it will not take effect on the next build, but only at the following build. This is why I never use parameter definitions in a Jenkinsfile, it's just confusing and a big source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    booleanParam(
      defaultValue: true,
      description: 'This is a boolean parameter',
      name: 'MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM'
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
          // some condition
          def myBooleanValue = true
          println "0: " + MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM
          MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM = false
          println "1: " + MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM
          // I need to set the value of MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM based on myBooleanValue
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Example222') {
      steps {
        script {
          println "3: " + MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM
          // I need to set the value of MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM based on myBooleanValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason it's not working on my end :/ Not sure why.

Comment: @chocho.boss On first run of the pipeline, script variable `MY_BOOLEAN_PARAM` isn't defined, because the pipeline actually only turns the parameters that are visible in the Jenkins UI before the job has started, into script variables. Only after the first run, the parameters are created and visible in the Jenkins UI. Accessing parameters through `env.` though never causes an error, it will just return `null` if a parameter doesn't exist.